# Finding URL on which the form was filled

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have set up a simple email id form which is reused on various pages. I have currently set up a mail to me each time the form is filled which includes the mail id filled by the person. However, I would also like to know which page (URL) the person filled the form on, as that would help our sales team get more context.

I tried to do this by including a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="msg" name="message" value="my_hidden_field">
```

Then I included a script at the end of the page:

```
function setWindowURL(){
  current_URL = window.location.href;
  document.getElementById('msg').value = current_URL;
  console.log(document.getElementById('msg').value);
}
```

I then included this parameter in the mail that I sent to myself (accessing using forms' POST API):

```
html: '<br><b>Email</b>: '+req.body.email+'URL: '+req.body.message // html
```

I saw that the console was showing the right information, but the mail was just sending "my_hidden_field" as the value of the URL. I assumed that this would be because the script ran before the page had loaded, so added a body.onload as well:

```
<body onload="setWindowURL();">
```

However, even this isn't helping out.

When I logged req.body, this is what I saw on the server logs: `{ email: 'example@gmail.com', message: 'my_hidden_field' }`

I would just like to receive the mail id and the URL on which the form was filled. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="msg" name="message" value="my_hidden_field"> this is the form field, with name "message". When I logged req.body, this is what I saw on the server logs: { email: 'example@gmail.com', message: 'my_hidden_field' }

Comment: Do you get any email? How is the email sent? What is the server language?

Comment: Yes indeed. The mail's content is:
Email: example@gmail.com URL: my_hidden_field

Server language is Node

Comment: Too little information, show your ajax function, which sends your data to the server

Comment: Using the forms' post api which is retrieved in express using req. Adding the mail content again

html: '<br><b>Email</b>: '+req.body.email+'URL: '+req.body.message // html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was using the same id multiple times on the page which was causing this error. Otherwise, the above implementation works.